# Monitoring programmes

Tags: spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics

I am not sure if it is a right place to ask this one but let me try.

Monitoring programmes are known for various targets and for various spatial levels.
They may include regions, countries or even continents. It is widely accepted that
monitoring systems are of increasing importance as economic activities and their
impacts on nature become more and more global.

I am looking for a various monitoring programmes. The best will be that related to forestry (but in fact i am seeking for anyone) like [this one](http://www.icp-forests.org/MonLvI.htm)

I am interested 
how do you evaluate the selected level I and level II indicators used in the [ICP
forest ecosystem monitoring programme](http://www.icp-forests.org/MonLvI.htm)?
Do you consider them exhaustive to get a comprehensive view of the state of the
forest ecosystems under the influence of air pollution?

Also if you have some examples in mind it will be great to share it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ireland private forestry is monitored by Coford. 
A couple of links

- http://www.coillte.ie/coillteforest/forest_facts/forest_health_vitality/
- http://www.coford.ie/iopen24/forest-monitoring-network-t-129_590_591.html

The following link points to an example of a water monitoring example, architecture, and API from the EPA in the US:

http://www.epa.gov/waters/about/arch.html

Answer (score 1):

[Planetary Skin](http://www.planetaryskin.org/home) looks interesting, but seems like a lot more form than substance so far.

> Under the terms of a Space Act
>   Agreement, NASA and Cisco will work
>   together to develop the Planetary Skin
>   to be an online collaborative platform
>   to capture and analyze data from
>   satellite, airborne, sea– and
>   land–based sensors across the globe.
>   This data will then be made available
>   for the general public, governments
>   and businesses to measure, report and
>   verify environmental data in
>   near–real–time to help them detect and
>   adapt to global climate change.